# Android Studio Login Page with php connect to localhost how start other activitie java if username and password is correct

Tags: java, php, android, authentication, wamp

I create new project in Android Studio. Did login Page. Did php file to check if username and password is Correct.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from employee_data where username like '$user_name'and password like '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo"login success";

}else {

echo "login not success";
}
?>
```

My java Code in Android Studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etnomedeutilizador, etpassword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etnomedeutilizador = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etnomedeutilizador);
    etpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
}
public void botaologinonClick(View view) {
    String username = etnomedeutilizador.getText().toString();
    String password = etpassword.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackGroundWorker backGroundWorker = new BackGroundWorker(this);
    backGroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    System.err.println("aspas");
```

My java (BackGroundWorker) code is this

```
public class BackGroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackGroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.1.79/login.php";
          if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            String user = URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");//guarda o nome de utilizador introduzido
            String pass = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");//guarda a pass introduzido
            System.err.println("------------------------------------------");
             /*/  if(user.equals("Nome de Utilizador")){
                   if(pass.equals("Password")) {
                       System.err.println("Entrou no if");
                       startActivity(new Intent(this, Pagina1.class));}
             /*/




            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result +=line;

            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Question: If my username and password are correct with my DataBase(localhost) i want to start new activitie in my Android Studio after message shown from php (Login Success).
[Login Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVfpz.png)
 if username and/or password wrong
 show message from php (login not success).
[Wrong Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x81HS.png)

To me more specified, application stays in "Login Success" message from php and i want it to start new activitie java in my Android after that.

Comment: You should better print an integer value in your php script which you can better evaluate in your android app then if login was successful or not.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Show me code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in login.php file check if the requested username or password or email (define your criteria) if exists in the database. If exists echo some text like 'succes' or 'failure' if not exists.
Finally override onPostExecute(String result) method in your asyctask to check if the response if equals to 'success' or not.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result.equals('success')){
               startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
               finish();
            }
        }
```